# While sending outlook invite getting error "not supported message.ics"

Tags: java, email, outlook, icalendar

```
    builder.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
                "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
                "PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010\n" +
                "VERSION:2.0\n" +
                "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n" +
                "TZID:Eastern Time\n" +
                "END:VTIMEZONE\n" +
                "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
                "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:" + calendarRequest.getToEmail() + "\n" +
                "ORGANIZER;CN=ORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + fromEmail + "\n" +
                "DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:" + calendarRequest.getBody() + "\n" +
                "UID:"+calendarRequest.getUid()+"\n" +
                "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Discussion\n" +
                "DTSTART:" + formatter.format(MeetingStartTime).replace(" ", "T") + "\n" +
                "DTEND:" + formatter.format(MeetingEndTime).replace(" ", "T") + "\n" +
                "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
                "PRIORITY:5\n" +
                "DTSTAMP:20200922T105302Z\n" +
                "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
                "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n" +
                "SEQUENCE:$sequenceNumber\n" +
                "LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:Microsoft Teams Meeting\n" +
                "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
                "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER\n" +
                "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M\n" +
                "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
                "END:VALARM\n" +
                "END:VEVENT\n" +
                "END:VCALENDAR");
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
                new ByteArrayDataSource(builder.toString(), "text/calendar;method=REQUEST;name=\"invite.ics\"")));
```

Here I am trying to send an outlook invitation through java code it's showing an error "not supported invite.ics".
I have checked form and organizer email both are same.
I am using outlook 2016.

Comment: Try to create a new appointment and export an invitation to to the ics format. Is there any difference between yours and automatically generated one?

Comment: What happens if you remove ;name=\"invite.ics\" does it work then?

Comment: It worked when i remove time zone block from here.
this code block {BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n" +
                "TZID:Eastern Time\n" +
                "END:VTIMEZONE\n" +}

Comment: Anyone know where the documentation is for sending Outlook calendar invites?